# Set the range for increment and decrement button in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, increment

I have created an app for my college project, it's an app to get the product quantity and store in data base.

The problem is when I decrement it goes below 0(-1,-2....) so i want to set the range, min 0 when i decrement and max 10 when i increment it.

Screenshot
[image: Screenshot]

this is my code..

```
 override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ViewHolder).bind(cartItems[position])

    holder.itemView.decrement_in_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        val count = holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text.toString().toInt()
        val count_new = databaseHelper.increase_decrease_in_cart("decrement", item_name, count)
        holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text = count_new.toString()
    }

    holder.itemView.increment_in_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        val count = holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text.toString().toInt()
        val count_new = databaseHelper.increase_decrease_in_cart("increment", item_name, count)
        holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text = count_new.toString()
    }

    holder.itemView.remove_from_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        databaseHelper.delete_from_cart(item_name)
        val cartFirebase = Cart_Firebase()
        cartFirebase.updateCart()
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using the Realtime Database you might also consider using transaction as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307610/how-to-save-users-score-in-firebase-and-retrieve-it-in-real-time-in-android-stud), or if you're using Cloud Firestore, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126348/can-i-make-firestore-transaction-that-reads-from-firestore-but-write-on-the-rea/53129151) out.

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ViewHolder).bind(cartItems[position])

    holder.itemView.decrement_in_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        val count = itemCountCheck(holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text.toString().toInt())
        val count_new = databaseHelper.increase_decrease_in_cart("decrement", item_name, count)
        holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text = count_new.toString()
    }

    holder.itemView.increment_in_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        val count = itemCountCheck(holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text.toString().toInt())
        val count_new = databaseHelper.increase_decrease_in_cart("increment", item_name, count)
        holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text = count_new.toString()
    }

    holder.itemView.remove_from_cart.setOnClickListener {
        val databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper(it.context)
        val item_name = holder.itemView.cart_item_name.text.toString()
        databaseHelper.delete_from_cart(item_name)
        val cartFirebase = Cart_Firebase()
        cartFirebase.updateCart()
    }

}

private fun itemCountCheck(value: Int):Int {
   if(value < 0){
      return 0
   }else if(value > 10){
      return 10
   }else{
      return value
   }
}
```

You can achieve this by writing a minimal function.

Comment: I write an answer based on the values ​​entered.

-1,-2,-3,-4 -> return 0 |||
0 , 1, 2, 3 ,5...10 -> return  0 , 1, 2, 3 ,5...10
11 , 12 , 13.... -> return 10 

Thank you @a_local_nobody

Comment: i initially thought that this _might_ cause issues but i saw you assigned the result of the function to a variable and then use the variable so i suppose it works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
val count = itemCountCheck(holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text.toString().toInt())
val count_new = databaseHelper.increase_decrease_in_cart("decrement", item_name, count)
holder.itemView.cart_item_count.text = count_new.toString()
```

You're

- reading the current `item_count`
- passing it to a function in `databaseHelper` and storing the result
- setting that result as the new `item_count` in the display

so you should probably handle your bounding logic in `databaseHelper`, since that's the thing that's doing validation, computing a new count and telling you what it is.

(Really `databaseHelper` should hold the current count internally, and you just call "increment" or "decrement" with the item name, so it can update and give you a new value to display. You shouldn't need to read the display to tell it what's currently in the cart, y'know? This way is open to bugs and security issues)