# Firestore: what's difference between Firebase.firestore and FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

What's difference between `Firebase.firestore` and `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`?

When do I want to update DB, which one is appropriate for this purpose?

And when I want to check the extracted result value from Firestore.

if I log it, it only prints the object name not result in string value that is contained in the object.

```
db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("userId", userId?.toInt())
  .get()
  .addOnSuccessListener {
    documents - >
      for (document in documents) {
        Log.d("결과", documents.toString())
      }
  }
```

If I print this, it throws result like below:

**com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot@b38fd47b**

I want to read fields and values of this QuerySnapshot, how can I do this?

---

share code and error:

var db = Firebase.firestore

```
        val stDocRef = db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("userId", userId?.toInt())
        db.runTransaction { transaction ->
            transaction.update(stDocRef,"name", "new name")
            null
        }.addOnSuccessListener {  Log.d("결과", "Transaction success!") }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aside from m y answer, since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's the difference between Firebase.firestore and FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()?

None. Both are creating the same instance. The first instance is created by using an [extension property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/ktx/package-summary#auth_1) of the [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/ktx/Firebase.html) class, while the second one is creating an instance using the [getInstance()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#getInstance()) method of the [FirebaseAuth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth). The latter one is also a singleton.

> If I log it, it only prints the object name, not the result string value which is contained in the object.

That's the expected behavior, since your calling `toString()` on the `documents` object:

```
Log.d("결과", documents.toString())
//
```

The `documents` that comes from the lambda expression is actually a document of type [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) which:

> contains the results of a query. It can contain zero or more [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) objects.

So you have to loop through the documents, as you already and get the data according to the type of the field:

```
.addOnSuccessListener { documents - >
    for (document in documents) {
      Log.d("결과", document.getString("userId"))
      //                        
    }
}
```

If you however want to run a transaction, which in my opinion doesn't make any sense, since you're only reading data, then please check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions), or my answer from the following post:

- [Can I make firestore transaction that reads from firestore, but write on the realtime database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53126348/can-i-make-firestore-transaction-that-reads-from-firestore-but-write-on-the-rea/53129151)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the `QuerySnapshot` Object , Hence it is giving you the `Memory Address of the Object`. To overcome this, try to print `document.data` as show in the below example.

> According to [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) use `Firebase.firestore` to initialize the `db`

```
val db = Firebase.firestore // Access a Cloud Firestore instance from your Activity
```

---

Refer the following links for CRUD operation in firebase with kotlin :

1. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write
2. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Thanks I use kotlin can i get language of kotlin of this code?

Comment: I have updated my code to contain kotlin . For more reference refer https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Comment: my code throws error message: Create extension function 'Transaction.update' I guess update function doesn't exist in transaction.. it is same for document.data. data is underlined with red line. can you guess any reason?

Comment: See the updated code for adding firebasedata

Comment: I add code and error shot on my post

Comment: I have posted the equivalent docs based on your demand. Please check out which suits for you